# Insert array inside array that it's inside array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements, dynamic-arrays

I have an array that contains other arrays.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'clientes',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'fecha_alta',
            'compare'   => '!=',
            'value'     => NULL,
            ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => 'fecha_baja',
                'compare'   => '>',
                'value'     => $trimestre['end'],
                ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'fecha_baja',
                'compare'   => '=',
                'value'     => NULL,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

I want to insert an array inside `meta_query` array based on a condition

```
if ($_GET['responsable']=='Pep'
```

insert this array

```
array(
            'key'       => 'responsable',
            'compare'   => '=',
            'value'     => $responsable,
            ),
```

What is the best method to do this?

Thank you so much

Comment: Method "better" than what?

Comment: Sorry for my english jeje. I meant the best method. I change this on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make like this:

```
$arr = [];

if(true){
$arr = [array data with true condition];
}else{
$arr = [array data with false condition];
}
....
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'clientes',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => $arr[]
)
```

or if you want to push data into meta array then you can use that according to your need